# getting undefined after passing values inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass certain values inside a function and based on that values i have to query the data in google cloud firestore but i am getting an undefined when i am trying to pass the values.
here is y tried way

```
 const {profileCampaignSelector} =require('./profileCampaignSelector');

const checkinReminder = async() =>{
    const end = momentTz()
    .subtract(2, 'days')
    .endOf('day')
    .format();
const profileSnapshot = await rootCollections.zyx
.where('timestamp','<=',momentTz(end).valueOf()).limit(5).get();
profileSnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
    console.log(doc.data())
     profileCampaignSelector('joined','user',doc.data());
});

}; 

 module.exports ={checkinReminder};
```

and here i am trying to get the values which i have passed

```
const profileCampaignSelector = async (stage, type, profile) => {
console.log(stage)
}
module.exports = { profileCampaignSelector };
```

execution file

```
const profileCampaignSelector =require('./profile');
profileCampaignSelector();
```

i have solved this way but don't know why i am getting undefined

Comment: Calling function as `profileCampaignSelector();` will give you undefined because you are not passing any argument

Comment: What code does './profile' contain

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri const profileCampaignSelector = async (stage, type, profile) => {
console.log(stage)
}
module.exports = { profileCampaignSelector };

Comment: But you are passing values to profileCampaignSelector from checkInReminder right? and that seems to be imported from a different file